# WhereColumn null in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-6

I need compare two columns in table, but if one least is null, the query return empty.

| id | name | original_price | sale_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shampoo | 2.30 | NULL |

```
$this->products = Product::whereColumn('original_price', '!=', 'sale_price')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want such query returns also Null value(s) you should use orWhereNull

```
$this->products = Product::whereColumn('original_price', '!=', 'sale_price')
            ->orWhereNull("original_price")
            ->orWhereNull("sale_price")
            ->get()
```

BTW : if both are Null, fields are equal but query will not be empty

Answer (score 0):

Just add whereNotNull on both columns, If one is null the query where conditions will not match and return no record

```
 $this->products = Product::whereColumn('original_price', '!=', 'sale_price')
            ->whereNotNull("original_price")
            ->whereNotNull("sale_price")
            ->get()
```

Comment: But I want that the query return this product.